# How to add Directive to Angular7 app on CodePen

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, codepen

I'm learning angular, I'm following tutorial on Udemy and checking docs. I'm I've created [Angular app on Codepen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/roPbZJ?editors=1010)

and now I'm trying to define directive but got Error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PointerDirective:
>   (?).

My code look like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[pointer]'
})
class PointerDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
    ngOnInit() { }   
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ PointerDirective, AppComponent ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

I've also tried different name (app-pointer) but got the same error.

The pen is based on [this one](https://codepen.io/enlcxx/pen/vmadQz) but here it also don't work.

Searching for this error I've got info that this may be circular dependency, but here I'm just having simple directive. What's wrong?

**EDIT**:

According to @trichetriche the code only don't work on CodePen, did I miss some file? How can I create basic Angular project without build process, using only script tags? How can I make Angular app work in Codepen?

**EDIT2**:

So I've figure this out:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[pointer]'
})
class PointerDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef) {
    }
    ngOnInit() { }   
}
```

If you know why `@Inject` is needed on CodePen and not on normal project add in the answer.

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzmyn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.directive.ts). The issue might be with your project. Could you reproduce it in either a new project or a stackblitz ?

Comment: @trichetriche thanks or testing, I've edited the question.

Comment: Why are you forcing the use of codepen ? This issue seems to be related to your project, just change it ?

Comment: @trichetriche if the code is working with compile then I don't need this for other reasons then codepen. If I would remove codepen restriction I would need to delete the question. I'm asking about Codepen.

Comment: Yeah, okay, but **why** ? Do you have some gun pointed to your head, forcing you to use codepen ? You could easily pursue your learning by using stackblitz ...

Comment: @trichetriche I know how to setup app locally, so not need for testing to have it online, Stackblitz looks the same as my local project. I like codepen it's where I have all my demos. This also may be of use for others that want to setup Angular app without compile. Also I don't use Codepen for learning, I only use it for prototypes or demos.

Comment: Okay, well good luck with your issue, hoping for you you will either resolve it or come to reason ! See you around :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOzXRd?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, it seems that transpiler doesn't use `emitDecoratorMetadata` option there

Comment: Codepen sends request to transpile ts code if we use typescript preprocessor

Comment: @yurzui I've added `@Inject` just before your comment. Does requiring this mean that it don't send that option and that's the reason why `@Inject` is needed?

Comment: I don't know if codepen supports that option. But without it we have to manually define all types of parameters we are going to use with Angular Di

Comment: With that parameter the generated code will look like `__metadata("design:paramtypes", [ElementRef])` but without it you have to use @Inject or `static parameters = [ ElementRef ]` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebXOzj. And seems there was one more option

Comment: `static ctorParameters  = () => [{ type: ElementRef }]` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zybOoy?editors=1010

Comment: @yurzui you can add this as an answer, I've resolved my issue with `@Inject` and then I wanted to know why this may happen. Your reason seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codepen example you're using typescript as preprocessor so that all your code is compiled by typescript.

Angular has built-in DI system that heavily relies on the types we provided in constructor in our ts code.

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
                  we have to keep this type after ts compilation
```

By default typescript doesn't keep that information after compilation but we can set an option called `emitDecoratorMetadata` in order to keep this type like:

```
__metadata("design:paramtypes", [ElementRef])
```

But codepen seems doesn't have such an option to change that `tsconfig.json` so you have to provide that type to compiled version by yourself.

Here are several options:

1) dedicated `@Inject` decorator:

```
constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef) {}
```

2) static `parameters` property on class type:

```
class PointerDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  static parameters = [ ElementRef ]
```

3) static `ctorParameters` method:

```
class PointerDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  static ctorParameters = () => [{ type: ElementRef }]
```

**[Forked Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOzXRd?editors=1010)**